# How to create customer attribute in custom tab Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-attribute

I have created the custom tab in manage customer section in Magento 1.9. Now I have to create the attribute in my custom tab but don't have any idea how can I manage the attribute please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of free extensions that can be used to create customer attributes.  I use [Zestard Customer Attributes](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-attributes-extra-fields-for-registration-form-1.html), which is primarily focused on adding fields to the customer registration form, but would likely accomplish your goal of creating a customer attribute for use elsewhere.  Otherwise, you may want to take a look at [These alternatives](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=7&pl=0&eb=0&hp=0&q=customer%20attribute&t=1&p=1).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have already created the attributes but right now all custom attributes are showing under Account Information Tab but I want to show these attributes in my custom tab section "Custom Tab". Hope you have understood my question